# Closure reason doesn't make any sense to me

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm referring to my own question:

[Is there any scientific proof that passive cell balancing can improve the life of a battery pack?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/659121/is-there-any-scientific-proof-that-passive-cell-balancing-can-improve-the-life-o)

asking about the effect of balancing on the battery life or state of health.

This is clearly a technical inquiry asking for an explanation. Therefore I cannot agree to the closure reason saying:

> Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

In opposite I think this is a valid and valuable question, it can certainly be improved and be better formulated, but it is a concern for anybody in the field who maybe confronted by questions asking how and whether cell balancing really has an effect on the life span of a battery pack. As a pack highly depends on the weakest cell.
I'm neither recommending products nor looking for a recommendation nor for places to buy them this is clearly not the topic nor intent of my question. I rather want to get a more profound insight in the benefits of cell balancing on the life span of a lithium Ion battery pack each of these topics (balancing, lithium ion batteries, and battery-lifespan are clearly on-topic here) is on-topic (else why would related tags exist) on this site. So if I can't ask this here then where should I ask?

Therefore I'd be pleased to understand how this question can be off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have reopened the question.
Please see my two comments on the question - one of which asks for more information from you.

The vote to close reasons are very broadly defined and the system does not always reflect what the close voters intended. Making the question easy to understand well (eg with related links) can help.

Answer (score 11):

In this Meta question, what you said about [your question on the main site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/659121/is-there-any-scientific-proof-that-passive-cell-balancing-can-improve-the-life-o) is: "This is clearly a technical inquiry asking for an explanation"

But your question on the main site did *not* read like a technical inquiry. What you actually said in the question on the main site is:

> My question is as follows: **are there any studies** that can show that passive balancing can improve the lifespan of a lithium-ion battery pack? (**Please cite** and explain!)
>
> Or could you at least confirm or correct the above logic as I understand it?

(My bold)

That can be (and probably *was*) interpreted as you asking people to find existing research (studies) for you, rather than a *technical* question.

That type of question tends to be poorly received here, since people could waste lots of time checking the same places that you have already checked and, presumably, didn't find what you are looking for. Out of the limited available closure reasons for those site members who believe it is off-topic, the shopping/recommendation reason is the one usually chosen for questions which ask for *other* sources of information.

If you are looking to understand about cell-balancing then asking a question about *that*, instead of asking for other people's studies, is likely to be much better received by the site members here.

Comment: I fail to see how asking for studies about a topic would be a shopping question. Shopping questions (aka "recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them") are forbidden mostly because *1) Recommendations quickly become obsolete 2) Often they have incomplete information 3) Product recommendations can have a significant opinion-based component 4) It starts to bring more financial interest to questions and answers* (according to https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6707/107479). **None of those drawbacks apply to a study/academic paper.** In fact, it's the opposite.

Comment: @dim - Hi, Re: "*I fail to see how asking for studies about a topic would be a shopping question*" I said: "Out of the limited available closure reasons for those site members who believe it is off-topic, the shopping/recommendation reason is the one usually chosen for questions which ask for other sources of information." I didn't say that they *were* shopping questions, I just stated what I have seen in the years I've been here. || You could start a new topic proposing that questions asking for other information sources (studies, papers etc) should specifically be on-topic, to get reactions?

Comment: I understand your post is about the possible reasoning behind the people who chose to close, and not necessarily what should be done or your own point of view. But since you were describing this in such a neutral way, in your position as a mod, it implies that you're fine with people choosing to close for this reason, here (although I understand you may not want to close it yourself). The thing is: on my side, I think such interpretation of the shopping question rules are detrimental to the site, so I commented. It may be worth a specific post, yes. I'll see.